# How to change table TD text color via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I can do HTML/CSS:
`<table><tr><td style="color:#f00;">text</td>`
and I get red text.

But I cannot do javascript:  `tbl.rows[row].cells[col].style.color = "#f00";`  There is no color change.

What do I not understand?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include a [mcve] in your question as a snippet?

Comment: can u share full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML you're setting the `style` attribute of the `td` element to a string with value `color:#f00;`, so you'd have to do the same in javascript:

`tbl.rows[row].cells[col].style = "color:#f00;";`

This is because the `style` attribute is a string which must be valid `css`, not a javascript object with properties like `color`.

Comment: to add specific styles to an element without altering other style values, it is generally preferable to set individual properties on the CSSStyleDeclaration object.   element.style="color:..." will alter the other style value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Comment: Is there any response for my commente ?

Comment: @BelhadjerSamir My response is that I was answering a very specific question that the asker had, not discussing best practices about modifying styles through JS dynamically in the general case. If we're talking about best practices, we might not even modify styles at all, but rather append to classList.